# Authorize and Capture for Subscriptions

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm a very newbie developer, and I'm having a very hard time understanding the documentation.
Basically, my client is offering a subscription, but wants to be able to decide whether or to take the charge from his clients. 
I was attempting to put in authorize and capture in a subscription button, but it is going through automatically when I test it out. (I put in paymentaction=authorization)- it worked fine when I created a buy now button, so is it subscription based...?

I've been using the Paypal button creator: Here's the output code I got...

```
    <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="C6U8GKAAHAHF8">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: Code? Are you getting errors? If you post code, make sure to blank out API keys.

Comment: Thanks, I added the code up top...

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't tell me anything that's going on with the account. You might have to create your own subscription code if the client wants to decide when to charge the card. Then it's not really a recurring payment. Subscriptions are for regularly times charges (usually once per month).

Comment: He wants the payment to be taken regularly, but before the first payment, to accept or deny the person...Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Did you look through this documentation thoroughly?
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/use-cases/uc_subscriptions-subscription-payments/

When it comes to taking money, if you have to hire someone with more experience, do it. You can't afford mistakes. Try to get as much done yourself as you can, but then hire a more experienced developer to check it out.

Comment: I've read and read, but can't seem to figure it out. Your probably right, I'll probably do that. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck. I'd hate for you to lose a client over having something not be secured. Don't worry though, you'll eventually be able to figure this stuff out on your own, keep at it.

Comment: Thanks. I found a workaround that works for the client:) were just adding a 3 day trial period, and if he want to deny their application, he'll cancel it through PayPal .

Comment: That should do for now, but you should definitely keep looking for a programmatic solution. If he gets busy or just forgets, he could end up with subscribers he doesn't want.